# Tomcat/HAproxy request timeout

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt, haproxy

I have a GWT/Java application with a statistics module that gives reports, running in Tomcat with HAproxy. One of the reports given by the statistic module accepts a wide range of dates, that can be a whole year, for example. When this happens, the execution time of the servlet may take more than one minute to compute and generate the results.
My problem is that, in production, when the servlet takes more than 60 seconds to resolve the request, the server returns a 504 error.
Note that this happens only in production. In development everything works fine (We already increased GWT's requests timeout).
At the beginning I tried to solve this problem increasing Tomcat's "connectionTimeout" parameter in the server.xml configuration file. Until I finally realized that parameter has nothing to do with the execution time.
So after losing a whole afternoon I'm thinking the 504 was always thrown by HAproxy. Am I correct? If so, where/how do we increase HAproxy's timeout so it waits the servlet for longer than 60 seconds to complete its task?

Comment: Might not be a programming question at all, consider this answer over at serverfault: https://serverfault.com/a/647072/114376

Comment: Thank you, it was not a programming problem. The link you provided contained the solution. The problem was caused by HAproxy, not Tomcat.